# Bundle analyzer for create-react-native-app

Tags: react-native, create-react-native-app

How to analyze react-native bundle size? App was created using create-react-native-app.

Answer (score 5):

You can add this library [react-native-bundle-visualizer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-bundle-visualizer) to your project:

```
yarn add --dev react-native-bundle-visualizer
```

Then

```
yarn run react-native-bundle-visualizer
```

should show a visualization of the react-native bundle.